# code to allow IE to download word document instead of rendering it in browser itself

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, weblogic

i wrote html code that shows link to a word document that exist in my web application.

`<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/content/docs/doc1.docx">
 doc
</a>`

when i open the page in chrome and firefox it downloads the file when the link is clicked but, IE does not download it, instead it opens it in the IE browser itself showing weird characters.
i want IE to either open the file in word or should prompt, do u want to open or save the file.
i am using spring MVC framework and deploying the webapp on weblogic server.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to have a look at mime types.
Find the proper mime type for .doc/.docx and set it up in the weblogic console.

Comment: hi Sam, thanks for the reply. but if that was the case then i think chrome and firefox also should not download the file, right ? but chrome and firefox are able to download the file. IE is causing the problm.